# trigger bokeh alert message on condition

Tags: bokeh

In a Bokeh server update function some filtering is executed.
Can I trigger a JS alert box on a condition?
e.g.

```
if len(df_filtered == 0):
   CustomJS(code="alert('no values')")
```

Comment: I started [basically the same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000045/bokeh-how-to-manually-call-a-callback-or-handler-from-another-callback) a few days ago. Sadly, no responses yet.